# npm install -g angular-cli sh: 1: node: not found

Tags: angular, ubuntu, sass

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

trying to install angular-cli in ubuntu 16.10 and I face the following error on **sass**.

```
/home/user1/.npm-packages/bin/ng -> /home/user1/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng

> node-sass@4.5.0 install /home/user1/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

sh: 1: node: not found
/home/user1/.npm-packages/lib
└── (empty)

npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /@angular/cli/chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.17
npm WARN @angular/core@2.4.6 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none was installed.
npm ERR! Linux 4.8.0-22-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn

npm ERR! node-sass@4.5.0 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.5.0 install script 'node scripts/install.js'.
```

**Note:** I'm on a fresh machine, setting up npm/angular for the first time.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Turns out sass still expects `node` in `/usr/bin/`

Creating a link, by doing the following resolved the issue

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```